# How to tell Git "I already have http://../repo.git in /home/repositories/repo.git, don't clone again"?

Tags: git

Various scripts often contain "git clone ...", and running them again and again makes Git clone again and again.

How to configure Git to override URL to local one if I already have this repository (including for submodules). Ideally Git should put all newly downloaded repositories into that common location and auto-reuse later.

I want something like this:

```
$ git clone http://q.q/q.git
Downloading the repository to /home/my_repositories/http_q.q_q.git
Cloning from /home/my_repositories/http_q.q_q.git into q

$ git clone http://q.q/qc.git
Downloading the repository to /home/my_repositories/http_q.q_qc.git
Cloning from /home/my_repositories/http_q.q_qc.git into qc
Fetching submodules for qc
Cloning from  /home/my_repositories/http_q.q_q.git
...
```

Comment: You can't do this. If you give `git` a URL to clone from, it's going to use that URL. You cannot configure it to first check some arbitrary *different* URL. It's up to you to programatically check for the presence of the local repository, and clone from that instead of the remote repo if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could clone clone and then use `git remote set-url origin <http_url>` to retarget it to the original repo.

Comment: No, it's for already cloned repositories. I want to run various bootstrap-this-and-that.sh scripts that downloads both tarballs and gits unmodified and avoid re-downloading Git again. It whould also be useful for multiple projects that share common submodules.

Comment: @Vi. Really understand why you cannot do it... Each git repo is the same. If you clone any repo, you could clone it again. In the `.sh` you could check if a clone exists, then clone it, otherwise clone origin. And yes.. submodules are always pain. I would prefer avoid them.

Comment: I'm looking to avoid needlessly cloning again repositories to ecomomize resources.

Comment: @Vi. Yes, it clones repo files too, maybe takes a lot of space, but as torek said you could use shared repos (with limitations). However, the question is, why do you need many repos in the first place? Maybe just checkout different branches in the same wc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git clone --reference repository` to share objects from an existing clone.  See the manual page's warnings under `--shared` and `--reference`.

You can clone the existing clone and then adjust its upstream (I see [kan already gave that answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18836504/1256452)).

Comment: Does it integrate well with submodules? Can I ask for `--reference` behaviour when recursively cloning submodules?

Comment: I haven't used submodules for several years now.  When I did we had our own scripts around them and this was easy to do in those scripts.  These days, I have no idea...